# IOS- viewheaderInSection in AQGridView

Tags: ios, aqgridview

I insert a part 2 in AQGridView [like this url image](http://mocku.ps/qb6o64). If you see the url image, now i'm working ok everything data in AQGridView,

When i scroll down AQGridView i wanna part 1: Image will scroll scroll to part 2: part2 will stop and if you still scroll AQGridView part 3: the data will be scroll (keep Part2 on the top).

If using uitable i using function :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but in AQGridView i don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridView.gridHeaderView = YOUR_VIEW_HEADER;
```